# JobScheduler doesn't work when application removed from recent app android

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I'm building chat application and I'm using pusher service for this. as I need my application received messages when user close the application I used JobService and it works correctly when user return back from application but when user remove application from recent app jobService doesn't receive messages at all.
this is my code
***PusherService.java***

```
public class PusherService extends JobService {

    private Pusher pusher;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Context context = this;
        System.out.println("Started");

        PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster(Constants.CLUSTER);
        options.buildUrl(Constants.KEY);

        pusher = new Pusher(Constants.KEY, options);

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                Log.i("Pusher", "State changed from " + change.getPreviousState() +
                        " to " + change.getCurrentState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {

            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        int userID = 21;

        Channel channel = pusher.subscribe(Constants.CHANNEL + userID);

        channel.bind(Constants.EVENT_NAME, new SubscriptionEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {

                Log.i("New Message received", "Message recieved");
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(event.getData());
                    JSONObject messageObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");
                    int user_id = messageObject.getInt("sender id");
                    if (user_id == userID) {
                        System.out.println("sent message");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("received message");
                    }
                    jobFinished(params, true);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        pusher.connect();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        if (pusher != null) {
            pusher.disconnect();
        }
        System.out.println("Stopped");
        return true;
    }
}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private APIService service;
    private final String TAG = "API Message";
    private int receiverID = 9;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        startJob();

    }

    private void startJob() {
        // Create a JobInfo specifying your JobService and its constraints
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, PusherService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(Constants.JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build();

        // Schedule the job using the JobScheduler
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        if (jobScheduler != null) {
            jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and this is ***Manifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestChat"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".PusherService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

so how can I make my application received messages when application removed from recent app